# Detect focus out of specific Pane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

How can I detect that the focus has left the specific pane? Because the pane (`StackPane`) is not focusable, I'm having trouble doing this. For example, I have a `StackPane` with `TextField`s and if I press tab several times, it leaves the focused pane and goes to the other pane. I want to prevent this kind of behavior by setting the focus back to the first `TextField` in the pane if you leave the focus of `StackPane`.

This is my attempt:

```
myStackPane().focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (! isNowFocused) {
                setFocus(node);
            }
        });
```

But I think that this does not work due to `StackPane` not being focusable. I also tried with `isFocused()` method like this:

```
myStackPane.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            if(pane.isFocused()){
                System.out.println("not focused");
                setFocus(node);
            }else{
                System.out.println("is focused");
            }
        });
```

But, as expected, it did not yield the wanted results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, when a child is focused the parent's `focused` property is not set to `true`, so checking if the parent is focused won't help you. You'll have to test if the newly focused `Node` is a descendant of the parent you wish to keep the focus within; if it's not, request focus on the appropriate child. Here's a rudimentary example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private static boolean isParentAncestorOfNode(Parent parent, Node node) {
        if (parent == null || node == null || parent == node || node.getParent() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Parent current = node.getParent();
        do {
            if (current.equals(parent)) {
                return true;
            }
            current = current.getParent();
        } while (current != null);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox innerBox = new VBox(15);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            innerBox.getChildren().add(new TextField("Field #" + i));
        }

        VBox root = new VBox(15, innerBox, new TextField("Field #4"));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox.setVgrow(innerBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener((observable, oldNode, newNode) -> {
            if (!isParentAncestorOfNode(innerBox, newNode)) {
                innerBox.getChildren().get(0).requestFocus();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Once the focus attempts to go to the fourth `TextField` it will instead focus the first `TextField`. **This is absolute**. In other words, no matter what (e.g. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, clicking with mouse, requesting focus programmatically) the fourth `TextField` will not be able to be focused—nor will anything not a descendant of `innerBox`. I'm not sure if that's desired behavior. To disable the behavior simply remove the `ChangeListener` from the `focusOwner` property (will require you to keep a reference to the listener). Of course, you can attempt to modify the code to make it more nuanced.